# Retain text in TabWidget when icons are changed

Tags: android

I have the text for the tab set in this way:

```
TabSpec tabSpecProfile = tabHost.newTabSpec("Profile").setIndicator("Profile", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_tab_profile))
            .setContent(intentProfile);
```

Also here is the icon_tab_profile.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/profile_tab_selected" />
<item 
    android:state_selected="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/profile_tab_not_selected" />
</selector>
```

I see that the images change correctly on tab select, but the text disappears. The text along with the correct icon is seen on the other tabs. Any leads on how to retain the text? Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: follow this [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/).

Comment: How do I change the color of the text? Default is white on android:state_selected="true" and grey on android:state_selected="false"

Comment: same as you posted  icon_tab_profile file but replace drawable with color tag.

Comment: Hi @Harry - I need to do both. Can you please help me on that? I need to specify both a drawable resource and color.

Comment: Can you share screenshot? In my code tab text is visible and icons are changing. Confirming that you are using TabActivity and minApi 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by setting proper style, see below code:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/TabWidget</item>
</style>

<style name="TabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearanceTabWidget</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearanceTabWidget" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_indicator_text</item>
</style>
```

create 'color' folder under 'res' and add this file,

**tab_indicator_text.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@android:color/black"/>

</selector>
```

You can change colors as per your needs just have set for demo,

hope this will help.